# save arraylist bitmap in arraylist in file in android?

Tags: android

I want to store a list Note class in a file. What should i do?

```
public class Note implements Parcelable, Serializable{
   private String title;
   private String note;
   private boolean setAlarm;
   private String dateTime;
   private String colorBackground;
   private String dayAlarm;
   private String hourAlarm;
   private ArrayList<Bitmap> image;
}
```

I tried with the following code, it was ok if class have zero image. But it won't working if class have images:

```
public void saveInfoNote(Context context, Object nameOfClassGetterSetter){
    File directory = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "serlization");
    if(!directory.exists()){
        directory.mkdir();
    }
    String fileName = getResources().getString(R.string.file_name);
    ObjectOutput out = null;
    try{
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(directory + File.separator + fileName));
        out.writeObject(nameOfClassGetterSetter);
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more code that you've tried.  Android provides many ways to write to persistence.  Local Files, Shared Prefs, etc...

Comment: i use local file, but i don't know how to save images

Comment: dont store bitmap, store file path in arraylist